# How-To Replicate/Migrate/Move SharePoint environment with new Naming & URLs?

Tags: 2013, site-collection, migration, url, content-database

Could you please help me out to accomplish the task below correctly and accurately?

Scenario:
I have a Test SharePoint 2013 environment that has a Web Application e.g. (http://Intranet.Corp.com/) with a Managed Path e.g. (Team).

The Web Application consists of 51 sites collections, and their details are like:

The first site collection:
http://Intranet.Corp.com/Site/Admin  => This site collection has its own content database which is named (Admin_DB)

All the other 50 site collections reside in one single content database which is named (Teams_DB), and their URLs are:
http://Intranet.Corp.com/   (Root Site Collection)
http://Intranet.Corp.com/Team/Management
http://Intranet.Corp.com/Team/Sales
http://Intranet.Corp.com/Team/Marketing
:
:

Requirement:
I have a Production SharePoint 2013 environment where I have to replicate everything I have in my Test-Environment, But with different Naming and URLs.

In other words, I need a Web Application e.g. (http://Web.Corp.com/) with a Managed Path e.g. (Team).

Also, I must move/migrate all the 51 sites collections from the Test-Environment to this new Production-Environment, and the newly moved/migrated 51 site collections with their content databases and URLs must be like:

The first site collection:
http://Web.Corp.com/Site/Administration  => This site collection has its own content database which is named (Administration_DB)

All the other 50 site collections must reside in one single content database which is named (AllTeams_DB), and their new URLs must be:
http://Web.Corp.com/Team/Management
http://Web.Corp.com/Team/Sales
http://Web.Corp.com/Team/Marketing
:
:

So, Could you please guide me how to achieve this task? I know how to Backup and Restore the databases in SQL Servers, But I am concerned about the different Naming and URLs.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Make sure the Both farm at same SharePoint Build(version) level.
2. Create the Manage Path on the target Farm( Team & site).
3. Now take the backup of the Content Database(Admin_db, Team_DB) from Source SQL Server
4. Restore the Content Database to target SQL Server
5. Now [mount the content database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607581(v=office.15).aspx) to target Web Application(http://Web.Corp.com/).
6. Now test the sites

**Note:** Now if Source farm and Destination farm on seprate domains then you have to run the migrate user command to migrate all users to new domain. If you have any custom solution in your source farm, those should deploy in the target farm.